# How do I find the extents of my data in an Excel file (.XLSX) using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, epplus

Given an Excel spreadsheet, how do I find the extents of the data? Is there a method I can call or a property I can check? Do I need to check cell-by-cell for nulls and then row-by-row? There's gotta be an easier way, right?

I just downloaded the EPPlus library this morning so I might be overlooking something basic. I also checked the sample project but didn't see anything related to this question in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the Excel Object Model, you'd use [Worksheet.UsedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange(v=vs.80).aspx) for that.

Using EPPlus, you'd use WorkSheet.Dimensions.Start.Row / End.Row / Start.Column / End.Column.